# how to get the imageview content description in main program

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to fetch the value of content description on the main program, i have no idea, can any one solve my problem ? thanks in advance.

Xml

```
<string name="world1">Image world1</string>
<string name="world2">Image world2</string>
```

The above two values are set the content description of ImageView1 & ImageView2

How can i get those content descriptions values on my main program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View class has `getContentDescription()` method.